# How the call stack is working in a C# application (Simple example given)

Tags: c#, recursion

I have never been much into algorithms. Currently I'm unemployed so I decided to learn more about recursion and how to use it. I've been through the basics several times, I know how to solve simple problems like `fibonacci numbers` and `factorial` but this is because those problems are most commonly given as examples when someone tries to explain recursion.

However today I started by making again a simple console application for calculating factorial, just to see if I can get something more this time and I come to this situation where I think I have a big leak in my understanding not only for recursion but generally how the stack is working and why things happen the way they do, and since this example is pretty simple I thought that maybe it is a perfect base where I can try to find some new approach to the same problem (how to learn myself to think recursively).

So here it is. For the factorial calculation I made this simple class/method for getting the number from the console. I just didn't felt like making everything static, but no particular reason at all to make it like this, I just did, so I ended up with this class :

```
class GetUserInput
{
    public int GetFactorialNumber()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number: ");
        int number;
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
        while (!result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
            GetFactorialNumber();
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

And in my `Main` method I have this:

```
GetUserInput GetNumber = new GetUserInput();
int number = GetNumber.GetFactorialNumber();
```

So what happens :

1. I start the program and I enter something that can't be parsed to `int` for example `dfgdf` and in y debugger I see this:

[image: First]

2. I get my `Error` and I'm asked to enter number again so this time I enter a valid number like `5` and I see this in the debugger :

[image: Second]

3. I get into infinite loop. Even if I enter only valid integers from now on I still see the first invalid call:

[image: Three]

and this goes on forever. No matter what I enter from now on if it's invalid the method just stays in the `Call stack` if the input is valid then the method is removed but I can't never get out of the loop once I've entered an invalid data the first time.

So based on this simple example can you explain what actually happens here. To be honest, at first I thought that this actually will work. I mean - I get a correct input, I get out of the `while` loop, I hit `return` and that's all, return, I'm out of this method. Then, when I saw that I get into infinite loop, I tried to explain to myself what's the reason for it and since I have a method that is calling itself I think I've created some kind of recursion, but this is where I get lost - how exactly the stack works and why I am not able to get out of it (in this case but in general too)? Because the main idea is for me to understand how exactly recursion works, can you explain me, how the `Call stack` works and how exactly my code interacts with it in order to get the result that I've described?

Comment: Your while loop never terminates, once result was set to true

Comment: Your input is also recursive, in the wrong way.

Comment: You should not be using recursion for this.

Comment: There's a bug in your code.  You should use `return GetFactorialNumber();` instead.  This is the *bad* kind of recursion, it prevents you from understanding your code, doesn't in any way make your code more efficient or elegant and only avoids crashing your program because your user gets exhausted first.

Comment: The simplest change you can make for this to work is to change the `while` to an `if`. Well, maybe not simplest but I think it'll show you what the mistake is.

Comment: `F10` and (`Shift`+)`F11` are your friends.

Comment: Yeah, I would appreciate a more detailed explanation on why things didn't work. I guess this is `bad kind` of recursion but could you be more specific what exactly is happening, what I'm not getting right in order to get into problem, and probably try to explain the connection between the recursion as it would be done and my code which is obviously an example of recursion bad used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    bool result = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
    while (!result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");
        GetFactorialNumber();    // here is the problem, no communication with caller
    }
    return number;
```

This input method has no use for recursion and while you could make that work, just do it iteratively.

Using recursion for a Factorial is artificial enough (in production code, use a `for()` loop).

Comment: Yeah, I know, as explained in the OP, it's just for self educational purposes and in fact just today I've read about the reason why recursion is not good for problems like factorial. Despite that it's still a very common example so at least could you be more specific on what the difference between `GetFactorialNumber();` and `return GetFactorialNumber();`?

Comment: No, consider it an exercise.  Although CSharpie already posted a solution. And learn to use the Debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Why not get rid of the recursion here:

```
public int GetFactorialNumber()
{
    Console.Write("Enter number: ");
    int number;

    while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");

    return number;
}
```

If you want to keep it your way:

```
public int GetFactorialNumber()
{
    Console.Write("Enter number: ");
    int number;
    while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error!");

        ** return **GetFactorialNumber(); // Code needs a chance to escape the while
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: As written in my OP, the whole idea is getting used to recursion. I just want (or at least try) to use this simple code to understand concepts that will help me deal with more complicated problems which involve recursion. That said - I thank you for the working example, but could you explain why exactly my code is not working (well obviously I should use `return`) but why?What does it change in the grand scheme of things?

Comment: If you are at the point of understanding recursion, you might want to look at thinks like the faculty-function, then e.g. quicksort.
Those are welldocumented beginnersexamples for recursion.
YOur problem here is that the code had no chance to break the while, even when a correct value was entered, since the int.TryParse was called before it entered the while, not inside anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the behavior, consider your code:

```
class GetUserInput
{
    public int GetFactorialNumber()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number: ");
        int number;
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
        while (!result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error!");
            GetFactorialNumber();
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

The first time in, you enter an invalid result.  Then you execute a while loop for !result.  Since you passed an invalid parameter, this while loop will loop forever.  Inside your loop you are calling GetFactoryalNumber recursively.  This will ask you again for another input inside that method, but the results from that will be scoped to that level of the recursion.  Nothing is ever going to bubble up to change the outer result to break out of the while loop.  Hope this helps your understanding.